# when I creating new project in Android Studio then color.xml file and some others xml file have some strange code in it

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

when I am creating new project in Android studio then color.xml file code contains this code

```
����   3 8  ( ) * +     styleable  InnerClasses , style - string . mipmap / layout 0 integer 1 id 2 drawable 3 dimen 4 color 5 bool 6 attr 7 anim 
<init> ()V Code
```

why this happening every time[image]. Any solution?

Comment: Which options do you choose when creating the new project?

Comment: Did you change the way AS reads xml files? Are other xml ok ?

Comment: I am creating Empty Project. my old project work fine. this happen in only creating new project

Comment: Look up in AS settings

Comment: Try to change your Project Encoding to <System Default: windows-1252> and also the Default encoding for properties file: <System Default: windows-1252>. then do Invalid Caches/Restart . **OTHER THAT** try to delete user settings folder ..\Users\%USERNAME%\ .AndroidStudio3.3